# How do I get past the Labion Root Monster in Space Quest II?

Tags: space-quest-2

How do I get past the [Labion Root Monster](http://spacequest.wikia.com/wiki/Labion_Root_Monster) in Space Quest II?

Comment: Save your game frequently!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with the other posters that there is no special trick, but I recall from the Apple IIGS version that tapping the arrow key once would start you walking in that direction and tapping it again would stop you immediately. I employed a double-tap keyboard approach to navigate the root monster (or any other tight space) in which I would give two immediate taps (taptap) and move one "pixel unit" in some direction.

If you're playing an emulated/Flash version and have to use a mouse I would imagine the difficulty would go up.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

This is the one in Space Quest II, right?

There's no clever trick to getting past it; navigate between its roots without stepping on one.

Comment: It has no shortcuts indeed, you must walk in between the roots.